# How to use a macro after another macro dbt in the same sql

Tags: dbt

I'm quite a new user of dbt and I need some help whith the macros.

The point is that I'm trying to execute a macro after another macro in the same SQl.

The first macro look up to the most recent "data_modificacao" register by the "id_produto"
and return it

the second macro use star to exclude some columns because the view has more than 60 columns, its a crap to call all them all the time

the code that I'm trying to apply the macros is:

```
on Produtos_Sem_Tratamento.sql:

with
    Produtos as (
        {{ registros_recentes(ref('stg_Produtos'), 'id_produto', 'data_modificacao') }}
    ),

    final as (
        {{filtrar_colunas_star(ref = Produtos,"row_number")}}
    )

select * from final
```

the first macro code is:

```
{% macro registros_recentes(model_name, id_column_name, time_column_name) %}

with
    added_row_number as (
        select
            *
            ,row_number() over(partition by {{id_column_name}} order by {{time_column_name}} desc) as row_number
        from {{ model_name }}
    ),

    first_register as (
        select
            *
        from added_row_number

        where row_number = 1
    )

select * from first_register

{% endmacro %}
```

the second macro code is:

```
{% macro filtrar_colunas_star(model_name, column_name) %} /* column_name é o nome da coluna da 'chave_altoqi' */

{%- set columns = dbt_utils.star(from=model_name, except=[column_name]) -%}

with
    colunas_filtradas as (
        select {{columns}}
        from {{model_name}}
    )

select * from colunas_filtradas 

{% endmacro %}
```

Can someone help me with that?

the error log is:

```
Compilation Error in model Produtos_Sem_Tratamento (models\marts\Zoho\basic\Produtos_Sem_Tratamento.sql)
Macro star expected a Relation but received the value: Produtos
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbt_utils.star()` does not work on CTEs. It only works on a `Relation`. In your case, all you're doing is filtering out the `row_number` column you added in the first CTE to the original `ref`. You can just pass in the `Relation` from the model into the second macro just like you did in the first.

You're not filtering any columns out of the original ref, so you don't even need the `except` parameter. But, I left it below to keep the example consistent with the code in your question. You'll get the same result if you take it out.

```
{% set src_rel = ref('stg_Produtos') %}

with
    Produtos as (
        {{ registros_recentes(src_rel, 'id_produto', 'data_modificacao') }}
    ),

    final as (
        {{filtrar_colunas_star('Productos', "row_number", src_rel)}}
    )

select * from final
```

```
{% macro filtrar_colunas_star(model_name, column_name, src_ref) %} /* column_name é o nome da coluna da 'chave_altoqi' */

{%- set columns = dbt_utils.star(from=src_ref, except=[column_name]) -%}

with
    colunas_filtradas as (
        select {{columns}}
        from {{model_name}}
    )

select * from colunas_filtradas 

{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Additional note - This isn't really logic you would want to put inside macros. The macros are representing your transformation and is probably not going to be reusable (you should just use a ref to this macro if you need it elsewhere). Unless there is a lot more to this code than what is shown for the sake of posting the question, I would just put the macro logic directly in the model.

Comment: the first macro is used in many sources to collect only the last record of the same id's, but when it runs, it always returns as view with the row_number column added into it. 

With the response of the first macro as a view I thought that applying a second macro to it to select all columns except the row_number that has been added. 

The both macros will be used on others sources to get the last records of the same id's and also to exclude some another columns :)

Comment: The point is that I'm trying to apply the second macro in the result of the first one